# How to write table in list item in different sheet of excel file?

Tags: python, excel, list, csv

I am reading multiple tables values in one variable. I have all tables in list format.

I want each table to be written in different sheet if excel in csv format. I alread wrote on script which write all tables in csv, but here all tables are in same csv file, so distingushing each table become hard.

```
df = read_pdf("all_n.pdf", multiple_tables=True, pages="all")
#df contains multiple tables in list format
convert_into("all_n.pdf", "test.csv", output_format="csv", pages="all")
```

Each there any way so that I can write each table in df variable in different sheet of excel file?
Each

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> In computing, a comma-separated values (CSV) file is a delimited text file that uses a comma to separate values. A CSV file stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain text. Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by commas. The use of the comma as a field separator is the source of the name for this file format.

CSV is not a format that can support multiple pages, since it stores the tabular data as plain text.